# Limit amount of LI and add more link

Tags: jquery, limit

I am creating multiple lists dynamically and need to firstly limit it to 5 and then have a "More" link which should be taken from the closest previous a tag with the class .parentcat.

This is what I have so far....

HTML/JQuery

```
<h2><a class="parentcat" title="" href="#">Heading</a></h2>
<ul class="subcat">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>


$(function () {
    var link = ($(this).find('a.parentcat').attr('href'));

    $("ul.subcat").each(function () {
        $("li:gt(5)", this).hide(); /* :gt() is zero-indexed */
        $("li:nth-child(6)", this).after("<li class='more'><a href='#'>More...</a></li>"); /* :nth-child() is one-indexed */
    });
});
```

This limits the amount of LI's being displayed but the variable is just finding first of many a.parentcat tag it should be finding the closest a.parentcat to the UL. Also probably a very silly question who do I get the variable into the .after() all attempts I have made fail.

Comment: Show the DOM structure please,

Comment: Your first `$(this)` makes no sense. You can simply use `$('a.parentcat')` at this point since you are searching in the whole document anyway.

Comment: I have added the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the URL inside the `each` loop of course. Otherwise the `.attr()` will always use the first element in the jQuery object.

```
$("ul.subcat").each(function () {
    var link = $(this).prev('h2').find('a.parentcat').attr('href');
    $("li:gt(5)", this).hide(); /* :gt() is zero-indexed */
    $("li:nth-child(6)", this).after("<li class='more'><a href='#'>More...</a></li>"); /* :nth-child() is one-indexed */
});
```

Comment: I have just updated it to show my HTML as well. The a.parentcat is outside of the LI as a heading.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `each` loop and store all of `href`s in an array:

```
var links = [];
$('a.parentcat').each(function(i, v){
   links[i] = $(this).attr('href');
})
```